# How to properly order multiple kafka with same event type topics by timestamp with streams DSL?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have multiple input topics from different systems with the same event type, e.g.:

```
topic1:
{ id: 1, timestamp: t1, content: "..." }
{ id: 2, timestamp: t3, content: "..." }
{ id: 3, timestamp: t5, content: "..." }

topic2:
{ id: 4, timestamp: t2, content: "..." }
{ id: 5, timestamp: t4, content: "..." }
{ id: 6, timestamp: t6, content: "..." }
```

and I want them in an output topic as:

```
topic out:
{ id: 1, timestamp: t1, content: "..." }
{ id: 4, timestamp: t2, content: "..." }
{ id: 2, timestamp: t3, content: "..." }
{ id: 5, timestamp: t4, content: "..." }
{ id: 3, timestamp: t5, content: "..." }
{ id: 6, timestamp: t6, content: "..." }
```

How can I achieve this? `KStream#merge` does not guarantee the order. The difference of the timestamps in the topics can be huge (±years).

Is the only way to use the Processor API? And if so, is there an efficient way to not iterate through all events?

Comment: Are the timestamps similar to the message timestamp itself? If not its impossible to do it as the an event with any timestamp can arrive at any point of time and we cannot just reorder events in the output topic.

Comment: Yes, they are similar. They have already arrived, so processing time e.g. could be t6.